# Raspberry Pi 2 model B HDMI no signal

Tags: pi-2, power, hdmi, retropie

I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. It has Retropie installed and it used to work fine. Now my display says "no signal".

What I tried after some research:

- Different cables and monitors
- I tried it with 5V 2A and 5V 2.5A power supply
- I made a fresh install to the SD card of Retropie using the Raspberry Pi imager
- I edited the `config.txt` in the root folder of the SD card using a windows PC.

  ```
  hdmi_force_hotplug=1, hdmi_safe=1, config_hdmi_boost=4 and 7
  ```
- LEDs (red and green) are both shining

No success whatsoever. It used to work fine, and I'm starting to think it's broken.

I am grateful for every piece of advice.